# Time from X not working as expected moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
 $.each(data[i].replies, function(m, n) {
var currentdate = new Date();


                    console.log(n.entry.date_entered);

                    check = moment(n.entry.date_entered, 'YYYY/MM/DD');
                    check1 = moment(currentdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD');
                     console.log(check);
                     console.log(check1);

                    var month = check.format('M');
                    var day = check.format('DD');
                    var year = check.format('YYYY');

                     var month1 = check1.format('M');
                    var day1 = check1.format('DD');
                    var year1 = check1.format('YYYY');


                    get = moment([year, month, day]);
                     get1 = moment([year1, month1, day1]);
                   g = get1.from(get);
});
```

**Sample** `n.entry.date_entered` : `2014-07-28 12:23:43`

For all the dates i am getting a few seconds ago don't know why

Comment: I'm a little confused where is n.entry.date_entered coming from? I'm guessing that's the one that's a few seconds ago, right?

Comment: So your problem is that all dates are a few seconds ago. Do you care to elaborate on that a little? `currentdate` should definitley be the current time so it wouldn't seem that all dates would be a few seconds ago unless the moment is messing it up.  Is that the case or is your problem different?

Comment: Also if you can tell us what the console.log statements output if you think it would help us understand.

Comment: It works now i converted the currentdate to toISOString

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the format mask that you pass in to `moment`.

In your sample you use `-` as the delimiter but in your format mask you use `/`. This way `moment` will not be able to parse the date and will give you the current date instead.

Try changing your format mask to `"YYYY-MM-DD"`.